# How to embed Markdown in Scala code?

Tags: scala, markdown, literate-programming

I know that in Scala we have sbt plugins which allow us to execute code embedded in Markdown, plugins like `tut` and `sbt-site`. But how can we do the opposite? I would like to embed Markdown in Scala code as part of comments.

E.g.:

```
// number.sc file
// # Markdown code 
// some text 
1 + 1
//res0: Int = 2
```

And the code will than be converted to markdown.

````
Here is how you add numbers:
```scala
scala> 1 + 1
res0: Int = 2
```
````

Does someone know if something similar already exists?

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution, i'm curious about it if yes.